# Will my application stop working if I sign it with a certificate and distribute outside of the Mac Store?

Tags: macos, code-signing, mac-app-store

I must sign my application with a 3rd party mac developer certificate, but I want to distribute it to my clients without going on the Mac Store. Certificates have a validity period of 1 year.

My question is: Will my application stop working when my certificate expires if I distribute it outside of the Mac Store?

Or the expiration date is only for the signing process and not for running the application?

Answer (score 1):

For distributing your app outside the mac app store (From mountain lion OS) you should sign it with developer ID certificate which you can get from apple and then it will work fine.